# Crossrider browser button icon is very blurry

Tags: crossrider

I have a browser button configured for IE, which uses an icon. The problem is the icon is pixellated and blurry.  I tried uploading various icons of different sizes (19x19, 40x4, 65x65), however the icon looks almost the same every time (pixellated and blurry).  Would you please advise if there are any steps I could take for the icon to show up clear on IE bar?  Thanks!

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing on? Also, what's that file type (jpg, png, ...). If you can provide the extension id, I'm happy to take a look at this. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: I am using a png image. Thank you for being willing to look at this issue.  This is much appreciated!  The extension ID is 39753.

Comment: Same for me in Chrome

Comment: @user3491514 In the extension I can see an image of 65x65 pixels. For most browsers, the optimal size is 19x19 though in IE even going down to 16x16 can provide better results. Can you add additional images of the sizes mentioned to the extension and I will investigate. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexGrande If you provide and extension id I am similarly happy to take a look at your issue. Please make sure that the extension contains images of the sizes in my comment to _user3491514_. Thanks

Comment: I went ahead and scaled the image down to 16x16 pixels and re-uploaded it. Went ahead and re-ran the setup, but the image still shows up blurry in IE. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was wondering if you have had a chance to take a look at this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Shlomo My id is 69311 in Crossrider. It is blurry in chrome too. I just installed it again to double check. Feel free to email alex@recognizeapp.com to take offline. Thanks so much.

Comment: @AlexGrande Regarding extension 69311, I can see that you need to upload an appropriate icon image apply it in the _background.js_ code using [appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setResourceIcon)